# VB.net weird datagrid behaviour - missing 2 columns?

Tags: vb.net

I am very puzzled as to why VB.net kept ignoring 2 of the columns in the datagrid. Here is my code:

```
    Dim dt3 As New DataTable("CableInfo")
    dt3.Columns.Add("Parameters")
    dt3.Columns.Add("1mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("1.5mm2")
    dt3.Columns.Add("2.5mm2")
    dt3.Columns.Add("4mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("6mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("10mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("16mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("25mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("35mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("50mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("70mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("95mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("120mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("150mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("185mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("240mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("300mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("400mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("500mm²")
    dt3.Columns.Add("630mm²")
    dt3.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Description", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20})
    DataGrid.ItemsSource = dt3.DefaultView
```

The datagrid shows this:

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Try removing the period (`.`) from the column name as a test, then try again. That is the only immediately apparent difference between those two columns and the rest.

Comment: It should be noted that the code is added default text column to the table, but adding numeric data.

Comment: @vbnet3d. I think you are spot on there....I remove the period "," in the header and it shows the columns data correctly. While this works, I still need the header to display the period ".". Any workaround for this?

Comment: Okay. I think I managed to solve this one. The trick is to use one of the character from charmap that looks like a period. Takes abit of trial and error to work though. thanks vbnet3d.

Comment: No "tricks" needed.  Use a sensible, valid db column name and use the `HeaderText` to display whatever you want.

Comment: @Plutonix. not sure how to code that bit. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: What Plutonix is referring to is the `HeaderText` property for the column in the `DataGrid`. Since you know which columns you are setting, you could set this property, and then you would not need the period in the column name.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your code but changed:

```
DataGrid.ItemsSource = dt3.DefaultView
```

to:

```
 DataGridView1.DataSource = dt3
```

and it displays o.k.

Comment: I am using visual basic via visual studio 2015 and it does not have datagridview...only datagrid....any ideas?

Comment: @Tofulover Datagridview isn't a new control, it's [available since 2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.7.2#applies-to) and [replaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagrid?view=netframework-4.7.2) the old DataGrid. It's definitely available in Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

What about add the objects as `string`? like `"Description"`

Comment: Tried that. Instead of the values 2 and 3, I use "2" and "3" and still the columns do not appear....

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to solve this one. The trick is to use one of the character from charmap that looks like a period. Takes abit of trial and error to work though. 
Many thanks to vbnet3d.